# Why Asserts equals 0 (zero) in NUnit Android Test Runner?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, nunit-3.0

As mentioned in the title, why is it displayed `Asserts: 0` in my NUnit Android Test Runner, despite there are two `Assert`s being called in the corresponding test method? Just curious if I was doing assertion the wrong way, or maybe the information displayed means completely different from what I think it does.

[image]

The test method is as posted below. Breakpoints on the two `Assert` lines are hit as expected.

```
[Test]
public async Task TestDeleteHistoryShouldEmptyTable()
{
    var newBookmark = new Bookmark
    {
        Id = "foo",
        Page = 100,
        CreatedBy = "john doe",
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
    };
    await _mainVM.Repo.SaveAsync(newBookmark);
    var historyBefore = await _mainVM.Repo.GetLatestBookmarksAsync(Helpers.HistorySize);
    Assert.True(historyBefore.Any());

    await _mainVM.Repo.ClearTable("Bookmark");
    var historyAfter = await _mainVM.Repo.GetLatestBookmarksAsync(Helpers.HistorySize);
    Assert.True(!historyAfter.Any());
}
```

**UPDATE :**

The problem can also be reproduced using the following test method :

```
[Test]
public async Task TestAsyncCounter()
{
    await FakeAsyncMethod();
    Assert.True(true);
}

public async Task FakeAsyncMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the first `await` transfer control back to the caller, _before_ any asserts?

Comment: @oerkelens From what I observed, the execution sort of goes somewhere else after every `await` line (including the first `await` you mentioned), but breakpoints on the lines that follow are still hit, if any (in my case, there are 2 breakpoints on each `Assert.True(...)` line).

Comment: I think the number of `asserts` is evaluated right after execution "sort of goes somewhere else". Of course your break points are hit, but if the asserts are already counted before that, you're out of luck.

Comment: [Some common pitfalls in async](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/)

Comment: @oerkelens Looks like you are correct. When I add another `Assert.True(true)` before any `await` line, the counter then displayed `Asserts: 1`.

Comment: But I couldn't think of any route NUnit might have taken that cause it to be able to conclude before the awaited tasks are completed. I would expect, a counter is incremented everytime one of `Assert` methods is executed, in which case should results in a correct count since it is indeed executed judging from the breakpoint being hit.

Comment: I think I will report this in [their github](https://github.com/nunit/nunit) later, since I've managed to reproduce the problem using simple fake `async` method, as in the snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a framework bug, as confirmed by [@CharliePoole](https://github.com/CharliePoole), one of the NUnit maintainer in their [issue tracker](https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin/issues/55):

> *"OK, I have to take back that last comment. It works correctly when the awaited method doesn't contain an await itself and is therefore processed synchronously. I'm seeing odd results when I include `await Task.Delay(1)` in the awaited method. So there is definitely a framework bug and it can even be seen in .NET 4.5."*

Let's just wait for updates in the issue tracker for now.

---

Updated issue tracker link : https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1499